# Check if ServiceControllerStatus is NULL vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

how would I check if ServiceControllerStatus is NULL/value does not exist with the code I have as follows:

```
Dim controller As New ServiceController("value")
            If controller.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Value Service running")
            Else
                Label2.Text = ""
            End If
```

Is there an "empty or NULL" function I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
If controller.Status = Nothing Then
```

?

Comment: Thanks for this. Still trying to get used to .net. I am trying to check if a windows service exists but I dont think my code above works correctly. VB gives an exception "value does not exist"

Comment: ServiceController("value"), are you sure the parameter "value" is correct?

Comment: I am just using "value" for testing and it does not exist. I would like VB to add text to listbox if "value" exists and if it does not then do nothing. However, at the moment its giving an exception.

Comment: I am handling exceptions with "try" and "Catch ex As Exception"

Comment: I think this will help you. It's a static function that gets the services. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a.aspx